# Combination of Voice Over and Speech Recognition in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, accessibility, speech-recognition, voiceover

I want to combine voice over and Speech recognizer functionality. I have survey and with questions and to help user to select the option, I added UIAccessibilityCustomAction, so when user ready to select he selects this action, which in turn activates Speech recognition, he pronounce selected option and after UI updated.

```
- (void)startRecognizingProcess {
     __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
     self.audioEngine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

     if (self.recognitionTask) {
         [self.recognitionTask cancel];
         self.recognitionTask = nil;
     }

     NSError *error;
     AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
     [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
     [audioSession setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];

     self.recognitionRequest = [[SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest alloc] init];
     AVAudioInputNode *inputNode = self.audioEngine.inputNode;
     self.recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = YES;
    if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
        if ([self.speechRecognizer supportsOnDeviceRecognition]) {
            self.recognitionRequest.requiresOnDeviceRecognition = true;
        }
    }
     self.recognitionTask = [self.speechRecognizer recognitionTaskWithRequest:self.recognitionRequest resultHandler:^(SFSpeechRecognitionResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
         BOOL isFinal = NO;
         if (result) {
             NSString *selectedOption = result.bestTranscription.formattedString;
             NSLog(@"RESULT:%@",result.bestTranscription.formattedString);
             isFinal = !result.isFinal;
             if (isFinal) {
                 [strongSelf activateSelectedOption:selectedOption];
                 [strongSelf.recognitionTask cancel];
                 [strongSelf.audioEngine stop];
                 [inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];
                 [strongSelf.recognitionRequest endAudio];
                 strongSelf.recognitionRequest = nil;
                 strongSelf.recognitionTask = nil;
             }
         }
         if (error) {
             [strongSelf.audioEngine stop];
             [inputNode removeTapOnBus:0];
             strongSelf.recognitionRequest = nil;
             strongSelf.recognitionTask = nil;
         }
     }];

     AVAudioFormat *recordingFormat = [inputNode outputFormatForBus:0];
     [inputNode installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:1024 format:recordingFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer * _Nonnull buffer, AVAudioTime * _Nonnull when) {
         [self.recognitionRequest appendAudioPCMBuffer:buffer];
     }];

     [self.audioEngine prepare];
     [self.audioEngine startAndReturnError:&error];
}
```

all works, except, Voice Over lost its sound.
When I press Home button and then ones again open application, it again has voice and works as required.
**So I have a question:**
Maybe some additional steps is needed to make Voice over again? Or I miss smth.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to found out what was wrong.

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:&error];
[audioSession setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&error];
```

During implementation, at the beginning I added these lines of code, that lived in memory, and when the app was sent to background - audioSession - deallocated.
So removing these lines fixed the issue.

Comment: Don't you need the AVAudioSession?